# Why the harmonic series appears when we stack a pile of books?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, equilibrium, statics

lets say we have some books resting on the floor.I am trying to find the maximum protuberance that the books can achieve.we see that the books on top of the initial book must have the center of mass in the edge of the initial book the formula for thee cneetr of mass is:

$$x_{cm} = \frac{mx_1+mx_2+...+mx_n}{m_1+m_2+...+m_n}$$

lets assume the mass of the books is one hence:
$$\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}$$

I am trying to find how much of a protuberance we can achieve with n books

my question is why the sequence:

$$\frac{1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n}{2}$$

appears here?

I see that if we take the origin at the edge of the first book we see that the distance of the edge to the first book center of mass is 1/2 and if we take the books over that book as one object I see where the 2 in the denominator comes from the avarage of two objects but I dont see the rest of the sequence in the numerator?

Comment: I see that the sequence maybe the distance from de edge of the first book to the center of mass of that upper object (pile of  books)

Comment: note In my first sentece I refer to that the center of gravity of the stack must be exaclty over the edge of the first book

Comment: or what is the correct sequence that descibes the overhang?afther n blocks

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. If you take 3 books as one object, how far out does it stick? N books as one object?

Comment: 1/2 +1/3 +1/4?. I would like to see some geometric proof

Comment: @mmesser314 update I think is 1 +1/2 + 1/4

Comment: update: (1 + 1/3+ 1/2)/ 2?

Comment: Just watch Mathologer on this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQE6-PLcGwU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume we have a stack of $N$ books balanced on the edge of a table and that the edge of the top book extends $x(N)$ book lengths horizontally. I'm putting the books on a table so that all books contribute to the overhang. To add another book, let's lift the whole stack, put the new book on the table with the book edge aligned with the table edge, and set the stack back down in the same position. If we set the origin at the table edge, the center of mass of the old stack $c(N)$ of books was at zero since it was balanced. With the new book, the center of mass is now
$$c(N+1) = \frac{0\times N + 1(-1/2)}{N+1} = -\frac{1}{2(N+1)}$$
with masses measured in book masses. The negative means that the center of mass is now over the table away from the edge. We can now push the entire stack that distance towards the edge, resulting in a new extention of
$$x(N+1) = x(N) + \frac{1}{2(N+1)}.$$

Since we know that $x(1) = 1/2,$ we can figure out the whole series one-by-one:
$$x(1) = 1/2$$
$$x(2) = 1/2 + 1/4$$
$$x(3) = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/6$$
$$x(N) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots \frac{1}{N}\right)$$

The harmonic series comes about because every book shifts the center of mass by an amount inversely proportional to the number of books already in the stack.

Comment: Most intuitive explanation so far